# during opening an excel file with java i have this error: Warning: Usage of a local non-builtin name

Tags: java, excel, jxl

when i try to open an excel file i have this error message.
Warning:  Usage of a local non-builtin name

My excel file file contains more than 1600 rows
if i try the same code and open a small excel file, it's working.

Why please?

I use JXL
thank you

Comment: You have asked [this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123226/during-opening-an-excel-file-with-java-i-have-this-error-warning-usage-of-a-loc) yesterday, and still did not supply much more information which could be useful for someone helping.

Comment: Look at the formulae in your workbook: it's probable that one of them is using either a user-defined function, or a function from an external function pack.

Answer (score 4):

WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
                        wbSettings.setSuppressWarnings(true);

Comment: This answer seems a bit extreme as it will suppress all warnings which some may be useful.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be just a warning, and not an error related to the excel file, not the parsing of the file, i'd just ignore it. Here is the code that generates that warning:

```
// Add all the local names to the specific sheets
913       for (Iterator it = localNames.iterator() ; it.hasNext() ;)
914       {
915         NameRecord nr  = (NameRecord) it.next();
916   
917         if (nr.getBuiltInName() == null)
918         {
919           logger.warn("Usage of a local non-builtin name");
920         } 
921         else if (nr.getBuiltInName() == BuiltInName.PRINT_AREA || 
922                  nr.getBuiltInName() == BuiltInName.PRINT_TITLES)
923         {
924           // appears to use the internal tab number rather than the
925           // external sheet index
926           SheetImpl s = (SheetImpl) sheets.get(nr.getSheetRef() - 1);
927           s.addLocalName(nr);
928         }
929       }
930     }
```

Answer (score 0):

user618111,

It is likely a problem in your large Excel file.
Go to Menu Formulas and click on Name Manager. You very likely see a Name that has a bad value (#REF!).

If the excel file generation is in your control, you can fix it. Else, i suggest you just ignore it.

Comment: @codestar I checked my sheet your comment is not applicable in my case

Answer (score 0):

There can be one more scenario, where you have copied few cells from a different workbook. If you keep source formatting, and if it has a defined name, it will also be copied to name manager. Check if any such are there in and delete them.

Also, I had same issue when used MySQL Addin, which created some names in Name Manager. You may disable that COM addin and try again if that is the case.